# Java Point setLocation() removes value of HashMap<Point, Point>

Tags: java, dictionary, javafx, hashmap, point

I've got this HashMap:

```
private static HashMap<Point, Point> points = new HashMap<>();
```

Whenever I call .setLocation() for a Point that is used as a value in that HashMap, it will be removed - or rather set to null - from the value of its matching keys.

```
valPoint.setLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
```

The position of valPoint will be set to mouseX and mouseY, but when I try to access it from the HashMap via .get(), it returns null.

The .setLocation() function gets called from a callback function whenever I move the mouse.

I've tried reproducing that outside of a callback function. After putting a  pair inside the Map and calling .setLocation() for the value Point, it still returns the same Point when accessing it from the Map.

Why does this happen?

Here's some of the code:

```
private static HashMap<Point, Point> points = new HashMap<>();
private static Point drawPoint = null;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
//somecode
scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> mouseMovedOrDragged(e));
scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> mousePressed(e));
//somecode
}

private static void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    drawing = true;

    drawPoint = addPoint(mouseX, mouseY, lastPoint);
    lastPoint = drawPoint;

    //stuff
}

private static void mouseMovedOrDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    mouseX = e.getSceneX();
    mouseY = e.getSceneY();

    moveDrawPoint();
    //bla
}

private static void moveDrawPoint() {

    if (drawing) 
        drawPoint.setLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Comment: Which `Point` class is this?

Comment: java.awt.Point;

Comment: OK, so that is mutable; as explained in @Zilvinas answer you shouldn't use mutable objects as keys in a hash map (or in a hash set - just think about how a hash set is implemented...). Also, not really a good idea in general to mix AWT with JavaFX; it would be better to use the `javafx.geometry.Point2D` class (which is immutable).

Comment: I've tried to use `java.awt.Point` because `javafx.geometry.Point2D` doesn't allow to change the coordinates, as far as I can tell. Guess I will have to find another way instead of using a Map.

Comment: That's exactly why I suggested using it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point is not removed from a map. However, I'm pretty sure that once you change the location - you're changing the **hashCode** of the `Point` object, which will not match to any key in your `HashMap` any more.

See implementation of `java.awt.geom.Point2D.hashCode()`

```java
/**
 * Returns the hashcode for this <code>Point2D</code>.
 * @return      a hash code for this <code>Point2D</code>.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    long bits = java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getX());
    bits ^= java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits(getY()) * 31;
    return (((int) bits) ^ ((int) (bits >> 32)));
}
```

So the `hashCode` value depends on the `x` and `y` values and will change.

This is why your `Map` keys should be either **immutable** or at least have a `hashCode` value that does not change with mutation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.